# Axler LADR Proof of claim 8.19: Matrix of a nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a bit confused about the proof given in Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd ed.) for the claim 8.19

> Suppose that $N$ is a nilpotent operator on a vector space $V$ over the field $F$. Then there is a basis of $V$ w.r.t. which the matrix of $N$ has the form where the only non-zero elements are above the diagonal.

The given proof is essentially that 1.) form a basis for the kernel of a fixed nilpotent operator $N$. 2.) Extend the constructed basis to a basis of of $\mathrm{ker}N^2$. 3.) Continue in this fashion extending the basis until you hit $\mathrm{ker}N^{\mathrm{dim}(V)} = V$, as $\mathrm{N^{\mathrm{dim(V)}}} = 0$. Then reason why the diagonal and lower-diagonal can only contain zeros.

What makes perfect sense to me is that 1.) the extension process eventually yields a basis for the ambient space $V$, and thus a matrix for $N$ and 2.) why the first column (and perhaps additional columns) can only contain zeros: If $e^{(1)}_1,\dots,e^{(1)}_{h_1}$ is the basis of $\mathrm{ker}N$, then for any element $e^{(1)}_{j}$ we have that $Ne^{(1)}_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{h_1}\alpha^{(1)}_je^{(1)} = 0$, by assumption. Since the elements of the basis are linearly independent, it follows that all of the coefficients $\alpha^{(1)}_j$ must be zero.

(**Question/Part where I'm stuck**): But then the author writes that

> The next set of columns comes from basis vectors in $\mathrm{ker}N^2$. Applying $N$ to any such vector, we get a vector in $\mathrm{ker}N$.

Why is this? Why does $N$ map the basis elements of $\mathrm{ker}N^2$ to $\mathrm{ker}N$?

Comment: If $N(N(v)) = 0$, then $N(v)$ is in the kernel of $N$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see! Could you also answer the follow-up question: I get that then all of the extended basis vectors of $\mathrm{ker}N^2$ are linear combinations of the basis vectors of $\mathrm{ker}N$. But why does this then lead to the fact that the only non-zero elements are above the diagonal? Specifically, we know that the first columns corresponding to the basis vectors of $\mathrm{ker}N$ are zero. What would happen if some column after the said basis vectors had a non-zero element at or below the diagonal?

Comment: The fact that $N$ has a strictly upper triangular matrix relative to the basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ means that for each $i$, $N(v_i)$ is a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}$.